# WPF inherit base property

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

I am trying to propagate a string property in my windows to display a title.

In my base class, I setup a public string property with default get/set.

In my window that inherits the base class, i try to use the property as the Window's Title.  This fails.  However, when I pop up a message box, I definitely have access to the property.

How do I display a string property from a base class in a WPF window?

Code:

BaseWindow.cs:

```
public class BaseWindow : Window
{
  public string AppTitle { get; set; }
  public string AppVersion { get; set; }

  public BaseWindow()
  {
    AppTitle = "My Application";
    AppVersion = "2.1";
  }
  ... 
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<src:BaseWindow x:Class=... >
  <Window.Title>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - v{1}">
      <Binding Path="AppTitle" />
      <Binding Path="AppVersion" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </Window.Title>
```

This does not display any title in the `MainWindow`.

However with this in the MainWindow's CodeBehind:

```
public MainWindow() : base()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  DataContext = new MainViewModel(new MyEntities());
  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string.Format("App: {0}, v: {1}",
      AppTitle, AppVersion));
}
```

I get a messagebox displaying the correct information:

[image]

NB:  The multibinding syntax works.  I tried this with the property in the Window's ViewModel before trying to access it from the `BaseWindow`.

The rationale is that I want to display a subsystem name in the title for other windows in the app, such as 'My Application - Widget System' with only the subsystem's name in the subsystem VM.

Comment: 'Fails' means there is no title at all.  No errors.  Hadn't thought to look for binding errors as the MessageBox worked.  Will double-check.

Comment: You have to use SetValue and GetValue in the property setters and getters. Otherwise the .NET property is not coupled with the DependencyProperty

Comment: Changed, with the same result.  I've tried with `typeof(Window)` and `typeof(MainWindow)` before tyring BaseWindow.  None of them worked.  Looks like i need a BaseViewModel.

Comment: There is a wrong usage of the quotation marks: Use `<Binding Path="AppTitle", RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />`

Comment: @Clemens AppVer is corrected in the code.  I'll fix it in the question. My apologies, but I think I've made that a red herring.  AppTitle should still have worked, if that was the problem, shouldn't it?

Comment: Bingo!  Thank you @Clemens.

Comment: It really wasn't a typo.  As I said, it was only in the question that I got it wrong, and 'AppTitle' was correct the whole time.  It was in the 'RelativeSource stuff.  My original xaml only had the 'Path=' in the Binding, and then the wierd syntax (with commas & bad quotes) I was using came from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603803/wpf-bind-title-of-window-to-property) that Fratyx suggested I look at.  Anyway, thanks again (how to give you rep pts?)

Comment: The *weird* syntax was (valid) XML attribute syntax, while in a MultiBinding you have to use XML tag syntax. Just accept the answer given by Fratyx. It now shows the correct solution of your problem.

Comment: Huh.  Why the close vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binding in your XAML code for `MainWindow` refers to the DataContext of this Window. That is set to `MainWindowModel`. So the framework tries to bind to a property `AppTitle` of the `MainWindowModel` object. But your property is defined in the window class.

So you have to understand: the bindings does not bind to properties of the own class but to properties of the DataContext you set.

You can set `DataContext=this` in window constructor. That would show the title but of course it would contradict your intention.

Better use RelativeSource Bindings:

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - v{1}">
    <Binding Path="AppTitle" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
    <Binding Path="AppVersion" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Be aware that this way will not reflect changes on AppTitle and AppVersion after the constructor call. So you should make these property setters private (or protected).

If you want to change the properties afterwards you have to use dependency properties or implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I'm trying the DependencyProperty idea, but it is still not displaying.  Is RelativeSource Self, or should it be an AncestorType?

Comment: No, if it is a DependencyProperty of the window class it should be possible to reference it with RelativeSource Self. Did you implement all the `DependencyProperty.Register` stuff in the window class?

Comment: Just found explicit code for it: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603803/wpf-bind-title-of-window-to-property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603803/wpf-bind-title-of-window-to-property). See the answer of Louis Kottmann

Comment: I think I've registered it properly.  Edited the question.

Comment: @Clemens: It makes sense as it works as DependencyProperty and it do NOT work as simple property. Your were right if it were a binding to DataContext

Comment: That's plain wrong. The source property of a Binding does not need to be a dependency property. Did you understand the actual error? The wrong property path, i.e. `AppVersion`vs `AppVer`?

Comment: "Whoops" on the AppVer/AppVersion.  It changed since I started the question.  It is 'AppVersion' throughout the code.

Comment: @mcalex with `public string AppVersion { get; set; }` and the RelativeSource Bindings shown here it works! No need for a dependency property.

Comment: Yes you are right. It works because it is initialized in base class. But you should make the setter private because every change after InitializeComponent in MainWindow won't have a effect as normal properties do not have a notification mechanism

Comment: It would also work when the properties were set in the derived MainWindow constructor, *before* InitializeComponent. The setters should therefore be protected.

Comment: Things you shouldn't do ... :-)

Comment: @Clemens  yes ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Your properties are defined in your view, not your view model which is your DataContext used for the binding.

Either move the properties to the (base) view model or you could make them static and reference them by `{x:Static viewNamespace:BaseWindow.AppVersion}` in your binding. The cleanest choice is the first one as a view should not contain data.